# Trying to create an array of DateTime objects -- Datetime[]

Tags: asp.net, arrays, datetime

My brain doesn't seem to be working today. I googled around for this and just couldn't find it, which seems kind of strange since this is such a basic question that I can typically find out very quickly.

I'm trying to create an array of DateTime objects.  I can't use a List.

```
        DateTime[] dates 
        dates[0] = Convert.ToDateTime("12/01/2009");
        dates[1] = DateTime.Now;
```

However, I get an error, stating use of unassigned local variable.

So... how do I create the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using a basic array, you need to instantiate the array before you can assign items to it:

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[2];
dates[0] = Convert.ToDateTime("12/01/2009");
dates[1] = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 5):

Give it the array length :)

```
 DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[5];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[] {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate your array:

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime[] dt = new DateTime[2];
        DateTime[] dt = new DateTime[2] { new DateTime(), new DateTime()};
        DateTime[] dt = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(), new DateTime()};
        DateTime[] dt = { new DateTime(), new DateTime()};
```